# Length of Flask's flash message

Tags: python, flask

What I wanted to output via `flask.flash`:

```
flash("You need to select products before you can order flyers. <br/>"
      "You can't order only flyers.", "error")
```

But alas, nothing is showing. The `get_flashed_messages` list is empty. But when I do this:

```
flash("You need to select products before you can order flye.", "error")
```

The message does appear. But again when I do this (added one character):

```
flash("You need to select products before you can order flyer.", "error")
```

The message isn't showing again. Is there a maximum length of 54 characters that flash will show? I can't find anything related to this issue.

Comment: What else is being stored in the session? Are you perhaps overloading `SESSION` with too much info?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yes I had a lot of information in my SESSION. I removed some and the message appeared. Thanks! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash messages are stored in the `SESSION`, which by default uses a cookie to track the information.

You are putting too much information into the session, leaving your browser to reject the cookie.

Comment: As I looked further in the `session` issue, I found that Chrome's max-cookie length is 4096, so putting too much info invalidates the cookie. I switched over to Server-Side Sessions.